# hex2bin() returning a base64 encoded string

Tags: php

This is one of those situations that puzzles me to a point where I give up. I have a PHP page with a very simple task, here is what it does:

```
//r contains hexadecimal representation of an ordinary ASCII string, not base 64 encoded
if (isset($_GET['r'])){
    $r = $_GET['r'];
    $r = hex2bin($r);
    
    //at this point $r contain a base64 encoded string
    //and precisely the same string it was initially parsed into hexadecimal
    //so it is not only converting to binary/ascii but also encoding for some reason
}
```

So way before any sanitization or anything I just cannot convert the string back to binary, what puzzles me (if receiving a base64 encoded string was not enough) is that if I run the same thing on a `test.php` page, it works correctly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

    <body>      

<?php

$r = $_GET['r'];

$r = hex2bin($r);       

echo $r;

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

But oddities are not over, if I try to decode the base64 string in my script, I obtain back the same base64 string, there must be something really weird going on in my PC and specifically this page, for some reason. I'm running XAMPP with PHP 8.2 and I never received a base64 encoded string from a `hex2bin()` function.

The original string was `ÉGOÏSTE` some letters are not being converted back correctly using online tools (same script above) however they are replaced with the usual � converting it to `�GO�STE` so probably the sample text might have something to do with the problem, however why is it working in a test page running in the same environment? Why ever the function is returning a base64 encoded string?

I could not find a rference or case, when `hex2bin` will return a base64 encoded string.

Comment: Please provide a dead simple [mre] with input and output. Since it's literally just about a single function's input and output, that should be doable in a single line. Don't describe your interpretation of what's happening, just _show_ us.

Comment: @deceze it is all in the question, just read it

Comment: Everything except an actual value for `$_GET['r']` and the supposed base 64 value. Please post that. Simple input → output. Not several paragraphs of explanation.

Comment: Just because the output of `hex2bin()` *looks* like a base64-encoded value does not mean the `hex2bin()` is doing any base64 encoding, e.g. `hex2bin("534756736247383d")` returns "SGVsbG8=" but it didn't do any base64 encoding.

Comment: In your first code sample, you have a comment saying "//at this point ..." but there is no code to *output* anything at that point, so *how do you know?* My guess is that there is some code *after* that point, which you are using to output it, and *that* is where the base64 encoding is happening.